# Users can add items to list but not view/edit them even with Contribute permission

Tags: list, permissions

A list used in the SharePoint is given some unique permissions. Most of the users have the Contribute right and therefor should be able to view, add and edit items. That is what I want. But users can only add items, viewing and editing is not possible (event not if they try to view their own entries). I searched the web somehow, but I always only found the reverse problem, that people cannot add entries.

The advanced settings page contains an entry "Item-level Permissions". This is set to "Read access: Read all items". The user with whom I tested has definitely the Contribute permission (I used "Check Permissions" to validate it).

Me, as a Full Control user, can view everything. I thought of a column that maybe needs special rights, but I don't think so.

```
Title                Single line of text
Priority             Choice
Status               Choice
% Complete           Number
Caretaker            Person or Group
Description          Multiple lines of text
Start Date           Date and Time
Due Date             Date and Time
Business Case        Multiple lines of text
Cluster              Choice
TK                   Choice
Collaborators        Person or Group
Review Needed        Yes/No
Update               Multiple lines of text (this is the only versioned field)
Created By           Person or Group
Modified By          Person or Group
```

Comment: Items have unique permissions or inherited from the list? Any custom event receivers or workflows on the list? You checked with "Check permissions" on an item or on the list?

Comment: I don't know. I just created the list on the "Tasks" template and added the needed columns. I'm new to SharePoint. Can I check item unique permissions? I didn't intentional made unique permissions per item. I clicked on 'Permissions for this list' and then 'Check Permissions'. So I think I checked for the whole list. When I go to 'Workflows', I see All, Task, Folder and Summary Task in the dropdown field. tl;dr: What I want is a simple list without any special workflows where everybody with Contribute can add, view and edit any item.

Comment: Check the permissions for one item. Go to item's properties and click "Manage Permissions" on the ribbon. If "Inherit permissions" is active then the item has unique permission. In that case click "Check permissions" and see what permissions has a user that can't see the item.

Comment: "This list item inherits from its parent (<listname>)". The user has: "Contribute - Given directly" and "Contribute, Limited Access - Given through NT Auhority [...] group" when using the 'Check Permissions' function.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Try with another new tasks list and a custom list. Be careful when deleting permissions. Don't delete Limited Access on the parents (list, web,..)

Comment: When creating a new list, everything seems to work fine. If I try to create the same columns in the new list, can I copy the contents from the old list? The old list is filled with a lot of data already. But what if the same problems occur on the new list? There must be a reason for this. Funfact: I created a library where the same permissions are inherited as the list, and everyone can add/view/edit everything...

Comment: Copying the items to another list is possible but you'll need to do it with code/script. Also try by inheriting the web permissions for the list and break the inheritance again. With that action you will loose all the unique permissions for the list so try it on a test environment first and remember the list permissions before clicking Inherit Permissions so you can add them back after breaking the inheritance.

Comment: I've found the reason but I can't find a solution. When I delete the versioned field, the access denied goes away and everything works as expected. Any ideas on this?

Comment: What type of field is it? You mean you removed the out of the box Version field? I guess you removed it from the view only?

Comment: I removed the multiple lines column (Update, look at the table in my question). Sorry for confusion, with "version" I meant the history function from SharePoint. Update was a history multiple line column. After removing the column, everything works as expected.

Comment: Strange. If a user has access to an item then it has access to all the columns of that item. If it's a standard out-of-the-box multi line of text column then I have no idea what may be the cause. Check the traffic with Fiddler and see on what request Access Denied happens. If you don't find a solution you can create another multiline column, copy the content then delete the old column.

Comment: Yes, very strange. I can reproduce the behaviour. Every list that gets a history column has this problems. I looked via the network analyzer in firefox: I get a 401 HTTP Unauthorized for DispForm.aspx and AccessDenied.aspx when clicking on an entry. Deleting the original column and creating a new one does not solve the problem. Any further ideas? Thanks anyway til now! :-)

Comment: Is this multiline column that you call 'History' some third party column?

Comment: No. I click on "create column" and select "multiple lines of text". SharePoint default in my opinion.

Comment: This happens no matter how you name the field? Just want to rule out the possibility of a Field Added event receiver doing something with the field. Any third party features on the site? Have you tried on another site collection or another web application?

Comment: I don't have access to other site collections or other web applications. The name doesn't matter (called it asdfhsddf).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18525/discussion-between-naim-and-the-wavelength).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users must have permission to view item versions in order to edit an item that has 'Multiple line of text' column which uses 'Append Changes to Existing Text'.

Contribute permission level has 'View Versions' permission by default but the permission levels can be modified by site collection admins.

Check Contribute permission level and make sure 'View Versions' is ticked or create another permission level, add 'View Versions' permission and give users that permission level.

Comment: That solved the problem. We fixed the permission together with the Site Collection owner. Thank your very much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and removing "multiple lines" didn't solve the problem for me.  I ended up giving the users permissions that allowed them to add items "contribute" or something, then created a default view where it had a filter ID greater than 2 AND ID less than 2.
Then, hide the view "all items"
Note: if they make a custom view they will always be able to see information.